# ¿Cómo imprimir campo FCK con salto de página?

Tags: genexus

Estoy con GX Evo15 (build 107258, java/tomcat) y tengo un sistema en el que el usuario guarda un texto abierto en un FCKEditor y luego genera el reporte pdf.  En ocasiones es extenso (mas 1 página). Pero el reporte sale cortado,  vi en este [SAC #32568](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,,,32568;;): Se implementó el formatear HTML en reportes PDF que dice ...

"6. Como en el resto de los controles, el contenido del HTML no puede superar el tamaño de la página del reporte; de lo contrario aparecerá cortado."

¿Hay alguna forma que se pueda imprimir lo guardado en un FCKEditor totalmente sin importar la cantidad de texto?

Gracias saludos
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Bruno,

Creo que para contestar tu pregunta en forma sencilla es "no", no hay... Pero, lo puedes tentar cambiar la solucion para una webpanel con un javascript para la impresion... O, quizas, hay un par de funciones para manipulacion de long varchars: gxmlines, pero hay que pruebalas....

Si realmente necesita como un pdf, hay algunas extensions en el marketplace que hacen manipilacion de pdf, quizas conversion de html a pdf...

Comment: Pienso que se seria una lástima tener que "esquivar" el concepto de reporte genexus que tanto resultado ha dado a la comunidad. Quizá desde artech tengan alguna sugerencia para estos casos.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de GX16 U11 se implementó una solución para esto, **[SAC #46755](https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=46755;;)**.